# Need tutorial for DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetopenauth

I'm creating a C# Winforms app that will allow me to edit my Gmail contacts. I'm very new to anything involving HTTP & security, so naturally I'm completely lost in the DotNetOpenAuth samples & documentation. I really wanted to be able to read a tutorial that describes how to use DotNetOpenAuth to obtain Gmail contacts.

Is there such a tutorial? I see that the samples have a GoogleConsumer object, but I'm not really sure what "consumer" means in this context. All I know about OAuth is that it allows one website to redirect to another (like Google) to login and allow that original website access to data. Since I'm doing this in a Winform app, I'm not sure how that translates.

Basically, all of this cluelessness is depressing me and I'm trying not to get burned out. Does anyone know of a tutorial I can read that will describe how to use DotNetOpenAuth to access GMail contacts? Again, I don't think the samples will help me since they seem to be using ASP.NET and there is no real sense of "here's step 1, then step 2, etc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the OAuthConsumerWpf sample.  It has a tab that demonstrates an OAuth consumer that downloads Gmail contacts.